# html5 canvas move ctx.arc on keycode press

Tags: javascript

How do I make my `ctx.arc` (circle) move on keycode press? I'm new to JavaScript game development.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")  
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = 800
canvas.height = 600

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

window.onkeypress = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 119) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(keyW)
    } else if (e.keyCode == 97) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(keyA)
    } else if (e.keyCode == 115) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(keyS)
    } else if (e.keyCode == 100) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(keyD)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi There. What are your `KeyW`, `KeyA` ... functions ? post full code.

Comment: You can't very well move things that have already been drawn on html canvas. Typically you would clear the canvas then draw it again in its new location

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive the answer not exactly matching your code, I simply wanted to show you in essence what working with html5 canvas is typically like. Every time there is an update, or in some cases every animation frame, you clear the canvas and redraw everything on it. There isn't really a 'move' capability, you simply save the coordinates as variables and change those coordinates then draw the shape in its new position after clearing.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let x = 100;
let y = 100;

function drawCircle(x, y, r) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
}

drawCircle(x, y, 10);

addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  switch(event.code) {
    case "KeyW":
    y-=1
    break;
    case "KeyA":
    x-=1
    break;
    case "KeyS":
    y+=1
    break;
    case "KeyD":
    x+=1
    break;
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  drawCircle(x, y, 10);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id = canvas width = 200 height = 200></canvas>
```